# Could not switch between browsers in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Iam trying to switch between browser ie on click of a button it launches a new browser it
is finding the handle ..the problem is it is not able to find the object inside the new browser searched with id,xpath,name etc can some one give me any suggestion on the same.
also it is able to match the url as well.

please provide me the solution on the same.
below is the code.

**//Previous screen**
Set windows = driver1.getWindowHandles();

```
driver1.findElement(By.id("findButton")).click();
```

**//switching handle for the new screen**

```
driver1.switchTo().window("Customer Search");
driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
int i = 1;
while(i<= 10){ 
    for (String handle : driver1.getWindowHandles()) {
       String myTitle = driver1.switchTo().window(handle).getTitle();
       System.out.println("myTitle value : " +myTitle);
```

**//customer search is the new window title**

```
       if(myTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Customer Search")){
           driver1.manage().window().maximize();
```

**//if i pass the right url of the screen that is also matching here i have given dummy("sshsj")**

```
           if(driver1.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("sshsj"));
                   {
            System.out.println("Url is matching");
```

**//But not able the recognise the object on the new window.**

```
            driver1.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/left/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys("kamal");
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to open a new window, it's faster.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jscript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
jscript.ExecuteScript("window.open()");
```

Then to switch windows, use the window handles:

```
List<string> handles = driver.WindowHandles.ToList<string>();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(handles.Last());
driver.get(url);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/left/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys("kamal");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the element may be present inside an iframe. In that case, you need to switch to that iframe before you can access any element inside the iframe.